# Trouble mixing TAP::Harness constructor args

Tags: perl, tap-harness

It looks like some of the [`TAP::Harness`](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP%3a%3aHarness) (v3.23) constructor args don't like to play together.

When I try to specify the `formatter` arg along with `verbosity` or `color` args, the module complains about the latter two being unrecognized. When I comment it out, it works just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use TAP::Harness;
use TAP::Formatter::HTML;

print "TAP::Harness Version : $TAP::Harness::VERSION\n";  # 3.23

my $fmt = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;
   $fmt->output_file( 'test.html' );

my $harness = TAP::Harness
                ->new( {
                         color       => 1,
                         verbosity   => -2,
                         formatter   => $fmt,
                         lib         => $^O =~ /win/i
                                        ? [ 'C:\\some\\lib' ]
                                        : [ '/usr/bin/etc/some/lib' ],
                     } );
```

**OUTPUT** (with `formatter` arg specified):

```
Unknown arguments to TAP::Harness::new (color verbosity) at harness.pl line 41
```

Comment: Just checked the [Request Tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Test-Harness), don't see mention of any bug that describes a similar problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like [`TAP::Formatter::HTML`](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP%3a%3aFormatter%3a%3aHTML) has its own `verbosity` and `color` properties:

> **verbosity**
>
> ```
> $fmt->verbosity( [ $v ] )
> ```
>
> Verbosity level, as defined in "new" in `TAP::Harness`:
>
> ```
> 1   verbose        Print individual test results (and more) to STDOUT.
>  0   normal
> -1   quiet          Suppress some test output (eg: test failures).
> -2   really quiet   Suppress everything to STDOUT but the HTML report.
> -3   silent         Suppress all output to STDOUT, including the HTML report.
> ```
>
> **color**
>
> This method is for `TAP::Harness` API compatibility only. It does
>   nothing.

---

So the arguments need to be passed to the `TAP::Formatter::HTML` object and not the harness.